# How do I put multiple lines in a title when using the apa6 class?

Tags: line-breaking, titles, apa6

Right now I'm using `\title` to define a title and `\maketitle` to display it.  How do I put multiple lines in the title? I need to adhere to APA 6th edition format, and according to the book I'm using, I need a simple title page with multiple lines, all of the same font and size.  I'm using the `apa6` document class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a protected `\parbox` with centered contents; inside this `\parbox`, you can use `\\` to introduce line breaks:

```
\documentclass{apa6}

\title{\protect\parbox{\textwidth}{\protect\centering A title\\ spanning\\ three lines}}
\author{The Author}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

[image]

The `\maketitle` command might result too restrictive for your purpose, so you can simply design your own titling information from scratch without using `\title`, `\author`, `\maketitle`, etc.; in the following example code I used a simple `center` environment to center the information and inside this environment you can format the information according to your specific needs:

```
\documentclass{apa6}

\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{center}
\fontsize{12}{14}\selectfont
A title\\ 
spanning\\ 
three lines

\vspace{1ex}

The Author
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How do I put this all in a size 12, non-bold font?  Another issue is that I don't want any "affiliation" to be shown.

Comment: Basically, I need a few plain, 12pt lines.  I'm putting the author inside these lines.  The extra \author and \affiliation commands are superfluous.  But apa6 requires me to use them.

Comment: @notfed: please see my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks, you certainly answered my question the way I asked it.  However, as a side note, I'm still totally and utterly lost as far as formatting this document to adhere to APA6 standards.  (Now my abstract won't show up).  Please help me understand one thing: is it that there is more than one way to interpret APA6?  My textbook seems to diverge wildly from what the apa6 package provides.

Comment: @nofted: then apparently you'll need to stick to \maketitle if you're not sure how to produce the various elements that the command handles (\abstract amongst others). As for the APA standard, I don't know. I've never used it since I work in a discipline not requiring it. This, however, is in the package documentation:

Comment: "Most journals in the social sciences require manuscripts to be formatted in com-
pliance with the American Psychological Association’s Publication Manual, which
is updated periodically. The 6th Edition, released in 2009, substantially changed
the guidelines for formatting manuscripts; these modifications rendered existing
A
formatting solutions (e.g., the apa L TEX class) inadequate for venues in which 6th
Edition guidelines are being enforced. The apa6 class solves this problem, and
provides some new functionality not offered by the apa class."

Comment: @notfed: If you want, we could continue this discussion in chat.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3462/discussion-between-notfed-and-gonzalo-medina)