# How to make a title of two or more lines?

Tags: line-breaking, titles

My document has a long title, so I want the title spans two lines.

I've use this:

```
\title{my title that must be in two or more lines}
```

but it doesn't work. How can I get it done?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I put multiple lines in a title?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/56174/how-do-i-put-multiple-lines-in-a-title)

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate -- the other question is about the `apa6` class and its somewhat peculiar [tag:titles] behaviour.

Comment: @Werner I agree with lockstep

Comment: All: I've edited the other question to highlight that it is focussed on APA6, which is then distinct from this general question.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Use the double backslash:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\title{First line of title \\
Second line of title}\maketitle
\end{document}
```

Comment: I had the feeling this messes up the metadata injected by hyperref, i.e. the PDF title contains the linebreak.

Answer (score 8):

Use the line break operator `\\`.