# Single Space Title in Article Class

Tags: spacing, titles, titlesec, article, sectsty

I am writing a paper in the article class with a very long title. Here is an MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{setspace} 


\newcommand\e{\emph}
\newcommand\tb{\textbf}
\newcommand\un{\underline}
\newcommand\txt{\texttt}

\usepackage[left=1 in,top=1in,right=1 in,bottom=1in,includefoot]{geometry}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage[small]{titlesec}
\titleformat*{\section}{\normalsize\bfseries}
\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{1.1\baselineskip}{\baselineskip}
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{\parskip}{-\parskip}

\title{\vspace{-7ex}\tb{\large A very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very long title}\vspace{-7ex}}
\author{}
\date{}



\begin{document}

    \maketitle 

    \blindtext

\end{document}
```

Here is the output

[image]

How can I close the gap between the title so that the title is more single-spaced like the rest of the document?

Before posting this question, I've consulted different Stack Exchange threads about narrowing the gap between chapter titles but none of the solutions there have worked for me.

Thank you!

Comment: What about?: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/56222/how-to-make-a-title-of-two-or-more-lines

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Unfortunately, the same problem persists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can obtain what you want with the `titling` package, which provides tools to customise the `\maketitle` command and using `\setstretch`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{setspace}

\newcommand\e{\emph}
\newcommand\tb{\textbf}
\newcommand\un{\underline}
\newcommand\txt{\texttt}

\usepackage[margin=1in,includefoot]{geometry}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage[small]{titlesec}
\titleformat*{\section}{\normalsize\bfseries}
\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{1.1\baselineskip}{\baselineskip}
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{\parskip}{-\parskip}

\usepackage{titling}

\setlength{\droptitle}{-9.5ex}
 \pretitle{\begin{center}\large\bfseries\setstretch{0.5}}
 \posttitle{\par\end{center}\leavevmode\vspace*{-5.4ex}}%\

\title{A very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very long title\vspace{-7ex}}
\author{}
\date{}

\begin{document}

    \maketitle

    \blindtext

\end{document}
```

[image]