# How do I manually break a line in the title of my thesis -- using the U of Maine package

Tags: line-breaking, titles

I'm using the [LaTeX class package](https://github.com/rpspringuel/maine-thesis) to write my thesis according to University of Maine formatting guidelines. I'm running into an issue with line breaks in the title. I'm required to break my title manually in a certain spot, but the following:

`\title{An AUV Simulator for Incorporating \\ Physical Feedback}`

gives the following error after running `pdflatex`:

```
! Use of \@icentercr doesn't match its definition.
<argument> \def

l.59 \titlepage
```

Instead of `\\`, I've also tried `\newline` and `\par`, but nothing seems to work (no errors, but no spacing either). I've also done what was suggested [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/56174/how-do-i-put-multiple-lines-in-a-title-when-using-the-apa6-class), but it gives the same error.

I'm not really sure how the class package does titles, and am generally have no experience with advanced formatting. Is there a way to accomplish a line break here?

(Note: `\newline` works, but the first line will be off-center relative to the rest of the page.)

Comment: Well line-breaking with `\\ ` should be possible (almost) everywhere, so this might be considered a bug in your university's LaTeX class. You should contact the maintainers of that class about it. Maybe they explicitly forbid manual line breaking in the title for some reason. For this site, your question is too localised I'm afraid.

Comment: Alternatively, you can use `~` to ensure that certain words stay grouped together. `\title{An~AUV~Simulator~for~Incorporating Physical~Feedback}`.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

For this particular class, you need to `\protect` the manual line-breaking commands (as **Stephan Lehmke** comments, this is not the behaviour for other classes; is this a bug or a feature of your university's document class?):

```
\documentclass{maine-thesis}

\title{Some Long title \protect\\ with manual \protect\\ linebreaks}
\author{...}
\degreesheld{...}
\degree{...}
\program{...}
\submitdate{...}

\principaladvisor{...}
\secondadvisor{...}

\firstreader{...}        
\secondreader{...}
\thirdreader{...}
\fourthreader{...}
\fifthreader{...}

\principalshort{...}

\begin{document}

\titlepage

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Does wrapping it in a `\parbox` allow for `\\ `?

Comment: @Werner no; that was also my first idea, but using a `\parbox` you need to `\protect` both the `\parbox` *and* the line breaking commands.

Comment: Excellent! Believe it or not, this was the last thing I needed to do... I can finally submit my thesis! I'll definitely have to let them know about the bug. Thanks!

Comment: @derefed I'm glad I could help. Good luck!

Comment: Is there any general approach for this without this bug in the package?

Comment: Is it a way of using `\protect\\ `  without affecting the `\fancyhead`?