# Not to have titles with broken words neither in the title nor in the header

Tags: header-footer, line-breaking

If have long titles in my document, and I do not want them to present broken words.
I saw this topic on [How do I manually break a line in the title of my thesis -- using the U of Maine package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/60493/how-do-i-manually-break-a-line-in-the-title-of-my-thesis-using-the-u-of-maine), but after using the proposal, I realized that on the header of the document, the lines where also divided into two lines as introduced with

`\section{This is a very long \protect\\ title that I divide into two}`

Anyone knows how to have the title in only one row in the header? It is sure that it enters in one line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `\section[short]{long}` as shown in the following MWE in order to get a section heading that is manually broken into two lines in the actual section and a heading that is not broken in the table of contents and in the header.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}


\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\newpage
\section[This is a very long title that I divide into two]{This is a very long \protect\\ title that I divide into two}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is quite what you were after but it's another approach.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\newpage
\section{\mbox{This is a very long title that I do not divide into two}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you but it is not what I was looking for. I need to write the title (in bold) in two different lines without breaking for example di-vide into two parts, and appearing only in one line in the header.